# Dereferencing a char pointer gets slower as the string it points to lengthens. Why?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

I've come across a strange problem: I have the following code:

```
int matches = 0;
for (int str_id = 0; str_id < STR_COUNT; str_id++) {
    if (test(strings1[str_id], strings2[str_id]) == 0)
        matches++;
}
```

It compares pairs of null-terminated strings using the `test()` function. `strings1` and `strings2` are vectors containing `STR_COUNT` null-terminated strings of the same length.

Depending on whether `test()` dereferences its arguments, this snippet executes in constant or in linear time with regards to the length of the strings in `strings1` and `strings2`. That is, if i use:

```
int test(char* a, char* b) {
    return (a != b)
}
```

then the running time doesn't depend on the length of the strings stored in strings1 and strings2. On the other hand, if I use

```
int test(char* a, char* b) {
    return (*a != *b)
}
```

then the running time increases linearly with the length of the strings stored in `strings1` and `strings2`.

Why could this happen?

**EDIT**: Full example of the problem here: http://pastebin.com/QTPAkP1g

Comment: One word: Locality. Longer strings spread the data out further, decreasing cache efficiency.

Comment: Thanks Raymond! Could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of data locality.

In the case where you are merely comparing pointers, the operation accesses only the memory in the two vectors. Vectors store their elements contiguously, so each memory access is to a location very close to the one accessed during the previous iteration. This is very good locality, and the cache smiles upon you.

In the case where you dereference the pointers, you are adding additional memory accesses to the mix, so the cache has more work to do, and the effect depends a lot on the implementation.

Extrapolating from your data, it appears that the strings are packed together in memory, so the distance from the start of one string to the start of the next string depends on the length of the string. Short strings are packed more tightly together than longer strings.

In particular, you may be able to pack a few very short strings into a single cache line. When that happens, a single cache line can service the memory accesses of multiple iterations. As the strings get longer, fewer of them will fit into a single cache line, so the cache efficiency decreases. Eventually, the strings are long enough that each string occupies a separate cache line, and the cache provides no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first case it can be proved that as long as `strings1 != strings2`, the condition will never be true. An optimizing compiler can just deduce that the whole loop will never have any observable side effect, so it can optimize it to oblivion.

Consider that `strings[str_id]` is equal to `strings + str_id * sizeof(*strings)`; let's assume that the `sizeof` is equal to 1 for simplicity (we can do this without loss of generality). Your condition then becomes:

```
if (test(strings1 + str_id, strings2 + str_id) == 0)
```

If the compiler is able to inline `test`, with the first version of `test` the code would become

```
if ((strings1 + str_id != strings2 + str_id) == 0)
```

or (successive simplified but equivalent forms)

```
if (strings1 + str_id == strings2 + str_id)

if (strings1 == strings2)
```

So, since `strings1 != strings2` (this is almost certainly the case) and since the compiler can assume that `strings1` and `strings2` will not be modified by external causes it can simply skip the whole loop and just do nothing instead. Doing nothing is constant time.

With the second version of `test` there is no way to know if the condition is true other than actually executing the loop and dereferencing the pointers on each iteration, so the running time becomes linear.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for this. I understand your answer, but I still don't understand why the other function (*a != *b) wouldn't also be constant time, given that `STR_COUNT` is a constant.

Comment: @Clément: Because in `*(a + x) == *(b + x)` you cannot remove the `x` from both sides and call it equal as you can with `a + x == b + x`. You have to dereference the pointers and compare the results.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't explain why it's slower if the strings pointed to are longer, does it? That's my problem.

Comment: @Clément: Of course it does. The loop executes `STR_COUNT` times. More times = slower to complete. What's surprising about that?

Comment: STR count is 250000, and never changes. What changes is the length of the strings which `strings1[0]`, `strings1[1]`, `strings1[2]`, and so on point to.

Comment: @Clément: Please reduce that code to the simplest example possible.

Comment: I've updated the code to make it as short as possible: http://pastebin.com/QTPAkP1g . For string lengths from 1 to 250, it draws twice 250000 random strings and runs test on each pair.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't get the analogy with the current situation.

Comment: @Clément: We might be looking at cache effects here as Raymond says. The runtime is *definitely* not linear with the number of characters; after ~60 chars I hardly see any meaningful increase, and at 60 it's only about 3x what it is at 1.

Comment: @Clément after looking at this in detail in Xcode (yeah, I had to integrate a different perfcounter system) and seeing the kind of output you're getting, I can (a) rescind my theory on STPA above, and it will be removed, and (b) agree with Jon concerning runtime affect. I see no changes in performance on my Mac, which is obviously a different runtime than your Win32 box.

Comment: Thanks Jon for taking the time to run the code. You're right about about the measurements, I incorrectly assumed the increase was linear. I don't know anything about cache effects though, could you point me to relevant resources? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot for running the code. I'm sorry that my initial question wasn't very clear.

Comment: @Clément: Don't sell yourself short. This is an awesome observation, and subtle in its nature. The question itself, though a little difficult at first to get, is very interesting, +1 for that in itself. Raymond's conjecture on caching is astute, btw.